# python nose: how to make test description available in the xunit format's xml file?

Tags: python, nose, nosetests

Each of my tests has a description in this doc string, like below:

```
def testExample(self):
    "This is test example."
    pass
```

And I can see it when running from nosetests

```
$: nosetests --verbosity=3 --with-xunit -x
....
This is test example. ... ok
....
```

But it is missing in the nose's xunit format xml output file(--with-xunit), is there any way I can make it available in that file? Or any other plugin could achieve?

Much thanks!

Comment: wow. No one has fixed this for a long time. I made a bug report: https://github.com/nose-devs/nose/issues/939